# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'value' error when reading the variables of a function

Tags: python

I need to use a function, inside which there will be another function and inside the 2nd function, there will be another two functions. And I have to access variables of the last two functions at the first function. However, when I use one parent function and two children function the code works. But when I use one parent function, one child function, and two sub-child functions, I can not read the variables. There is an error : **Error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 33, in  mas() File "", line 31, in mas khan() File "", line 23, in khan val=a.value AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'value'
**
The code I am using is:

```
def khan():

         def a():
             print("Function a is running at time: " + str(int(time.time())) + " seconds.")
             a.value=[1,2,3,4,5]
             
    
    
         def b():
             print("Function b is running at time: " + str(int(time.time())) + " seconds.")
    
         threading.Thread(target=a).start()
         val=a.value
         print("val",val)

         threading.Thread(target=b).start()
         
         

def mas():
    khan()         
         
mas()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<ipython-input-32-496d0a7b4c4a>", line 33, in <module> mas() File "<ipython-input-32-496d0a7b4c4a>", line 31, in mas khan() File "<ipython-input-32-496d0a7b4c4a>", line 23, in khan val=a.value AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in `a.value=[1,2,3,4,5]`? and please format the code to Python format.

Comment: could you add the whole error thread please?

Comment: I need to use the value list later @Guy

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-496d0a7b4c4a>", line 33, in <module>
    mas()

  File "<ipython-input-32-496d0a7b4c4a>", line 31, in mas
    khan()

  File "<ipython-input-32-496d0a7b4c4a>", line 23, in khan
    val=a.value

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'value'              This is the whole error @jimmie_rogers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the attribute `a.value` is created when `a` is executed, it will (obviously!) not exist until `a` has executed. You are calling `a` in a thread. When threads are involved, there are very few certainties about what gets executed in what order. In particular, there is no guarantee that, when your program reaches the line after the `Thread.start()` call, the thread has even started running, let alone finished! Furthermore, even if it has finished, there is no guarantee that any actions performed by it are visible to the main thread. To be sure of this, you have to use some kind of synchronization mechanism, or `join()` the thread from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Object.Attribute`, you should declare a class instead of a function.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = A()
print('Val:', a.value)
# Returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But if I use class instead of a function, maybe then I will not be able to use threading. I have to run functions a and b parallely. Can you please help me with that @Pro

Comment: @AlmasrurKhan you could try implementing something like this https://dzone.com/articles/python-thread-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @PRO's solution:

```
class A(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
a = A()
print('Val:', a.value)
# Returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

thread1 = mythread(1)

thread1.start()
```

This solution does implement the threading as well.